# Files copied to shared folder do not inherit permissions

Tags: windows-7, permissions, ntfs, network-shares, acl

I have a shared directory with the Guest account having Read & execute, Read, List contents permissions. I can access files over the network (e.g. on my tablet or laptop) without issue. However, my downloads go into a temp directory and when completed are moved to my shared directory. The files are then visible over the network but cannot be accessed (read) until I manually add the Guest user permissions on the file or re-apply the permissions on the top level.

If I understand - [Why are file permissions retained when moving files within the same volume?](https://superuser.com/questions/312655/why-are-file-permissions-retained-when-moving-files-within-the-same-volume) - the issue must be that my temp directory is applying permissions to the files, and these permissions are being copied to the shared directory rather than inheriting.

How can I remove all special permissions from the temp directory, or otherwise - how can I force files copied into a shared directory to inherit the permissions?

```
E:\>icacls _temp
  _temp BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
  BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
  NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
  NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
  BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
  BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just apply Guest permissions to the Temp folder.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try it and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you using the built-in Guest account? This account should not be used for security reasons and you can create a new user specifically for the shared folder(s), while also giving this user very limited rights. Create a group for that user and provide that group access to both folders- also remove this user from the Users group if it's supposed to be very limited.

Comment: Yes I've used the built-in Guest account so that I can provide 'anonymous' access - i.e. without having a type a uname/pword combo. In any case I don't see how this answers the question, if I create a new user for the shared folder I'd be left in the same situation I am now.